# Concise pointer arithmetic for mmap

Tags: c++, pointers, mmap, pointer-arithmetic

I've trying to `mmap` a piece of memory and then use pointer arithmetic to treat it as an array. The size of mmaped area will be changed by the application as different sizes and data types might be passed. This is what I've done so far which is working, however, I think there might be a better way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int num_ints = 10;
    int num_bytes = num_ints * sizeof(int);
    void *base =  mmap(0, num_bytes, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                       MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_PRIVATE, -1, 0);

    // Ugly way
    for(int i = 0; i < num_ints; i++)
    {
        *((int *) base + i) = i;
        std::cout << *((int *) base + i) << " " << ((int *) base + i) << std::endl; 
    }
    std::cout << std::endl; 

    // A better way
    int *ptr = (int *) base;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_ints; i++)
    {
        *(ptr + i) += i;
        std::cout << *(ptr + i) << " " << (ptr + i) << std::endl; 
    }

    // What I'm looking is base[i] = i; which leads to
    // warning: pointer of type 'void *' used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
    // error: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type

    munmap(base, num_bytes);
    return(0);
}
```

Any suggestion for a more concise way of implementing this?

Comment: The warning is from using `base[i]`. `ptr[i]` is fine.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce warning](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fffc573e12f1f0fc).  Can you post the actual code that produces the warning?

Comment: Urgh. Another `*(ptr + i)`. Why? What's wrong with `ptr[i]`? Too readable?

Comment: I've updated the question. As @MSalters said, the warning belonged to `base[i]`. The `ptr[i] += i;` would be the most convenient way that I couldn't find before posting the question. Thank you :)

Comment: OTOH `base[i]` is not valid indeed. What do you expect it to mean?

Comment: Thought, I might be able to use something like (&base)[i] and then iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really much left, is there?

About the only thing you can do to shorten it is `std::iota(ptr, ptr+num_ints, 0)`. Doesn't help you a lot here since you still have that loop for printing purposes.

A more industrial approach would be to wrap the logic in a class template, similar to `std::array<T, n>`. That might turn your program into

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  mmarray<int,10> ints;
  std::iota(begin(ints), end(ints), 0);
  for(int i: ints) std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

The plumbing is hidden in the constructor, destructor, `begin` and `end` methods.